# How to design custom list view in android?

Tags: android

[image: How to design a Listview of this type in which selctor should only be focused on list not the list icon]

Comment: From your comment on @Aleadam's answer, you should post your questions very clearly in the question body, i mean you should write what exactly you want to perform and where you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plenty of tutorials on the web for that:

- http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/
- http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/
- http://androidguys.com/2008/07/14/fancy-listviews-part-one/

For that particular case, my guess is that, next to the icon, there is a `RelativeLayout` with three `TextViews`, and using a custom background drawable. That drawable will define different background colors with a selector depending on the `android:state_selected` and/or `android:state_pressed` states.

Comment: thanks Aleadam,but what exactly i want is the selctor should only be focused on list not the list icon if you observe the figure you can get it..

Comment: If you have a particular question, then I suggest you to *write it down* in the question body, rather than tossing an image and adding a very broad title