# How do you inflate an XML layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I'm writing an android application which starts of as a listview, for which I've written a class that extends ArrayAdapter, populating each row from a database. When an Item in the list is clicked, it fires an intent to another class which I want to list the details of the item clicked, so I can inflate the view with the item details. For now I just want to inflate one TextView as follows.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

How would I go about writing the class for a details page which only establishes itself after receiving an intent? Do I need to extend something to override the getView method?

Comment: do you want to pass this layout to the next activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inflating you can use

```
public View myView()
{
    View v;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prob3_layout, null);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Custom Adapter to show your Values in List View.
Check out this [Custom List in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172866/how-to-design-custom-list-view-in-android)

Let me know if you find any difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what you want to do is write another Activity (a details Activity). You will have a corresponding view (XML) to go with this activity. You pass the id of the item clicked through a Bundle. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android) is another question which shows hows to pass data to another Activity (through an Intent).

So you would build a new view to show the details. In your new DetailsActivity.java that extends Activity, in your onCreate you would call setContent(R.layout.detailsView) - where R.layout.detailsView corresponds to an xml you created.